# Heroku not working properly with multiple dynos

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I did a `git push heroku` to update my app like I've done many times before. I needed to do a `heroku run rake db:migrate` to add a field to a model. No big deal. Except now I'm getting errors in my website that the field doesn't exist:

```
2013-05-28T21:57:37.050674+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: has_computer):
2013-05-28T21:57:37.050674+00:00 app[web.1]: app/controllers/time_track_controller.rb:36:in `create_check_in'
```

That is caused by a `.create()` command. But `has_computer`, the field I added with the migration does in fact exist in production. I can manipulate it and create records with it using `heroku run console`.

Is the issue that I have multiple dynos and I have to update Heroku in a different way than simply `git push heroku`?

Answer (score 1):

I did a `heroku restart` and everything works now. Wish I would've known to do that 3 hours ago!!!

Comment: it's a common mistake. Because the db:migrate occurs after your application has started Rails will have cached the schema and you need the restart for it to recache the schema.